# how to fetch data from a dynamically generated usercontrol containing a listview

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that contains a listview. Inside this listview I set the listvidew.itemsource = table. Then I create a gridview and add the gridview to the listview.view = gridview. This is all done in code behind and then the user control is added to a stackpanel in code behind as well. All this is done in code behind because I'm generating different grids in the app based on conditions.

Now I have a button on the page that I want to use to pull out the data from each cell(textbox) in the tables after the user has entered in info. I created a button called Test_OnClick that calls the event method - private void Test_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

What do I now need to do to get the data from the table in each usercontrol?

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF, that's what XAML is for. Post the relevant code of what you're trying to do so we can tell you the right way to do it in WPF.

Comment: no you don't have to do it in code. You need an `ItemsControl`. Please post a screenshot of what you need.

Comment: ok maybe I don't have to do it in code behind, but I have  and I would like to know whow I can pull out all the table data from the page after I click a button. I can't seem to find any page data in the object or RoutedEventArgs data

Comment: Delete all your code. It's plain wrong. Create a proper ViewModel and handle your data at the ViewModel level.

Comment: ok, I'd like to try that but don't know how. Can you give me any advice or pointers to help out? I don't have a long time to spend learning the ViewModel, is there any way to learn it in a few hours? If so, how?

Comment: post the full code and XAML you have right now, and a screenshot of what you need versus what you have. I'll answer this question explaining how to do it.

Comment: Highcore, I posted all code below.